# Writing Pandas DataFrame into Teradata database table using Jaydebeapi giving error

Tags: python, teradata, jaydebeapi

I am trying to write pandas dataframe into Teradata database using Jaydebeapi. I am able to read data from database easily, but facing problem while writing.

Code:

```
import jaydebeapi
import pandas as pd
case_detail_server ='server_url'
server_name= 'servername'
user ='xyz'
password ='****'
jars= ['/anaconda3/lib/tdgssconfig.jar','/anaconda3/lib/terajdbc4.jar']
#jars= ['/anaconda3/lib/terajdbc4.jar']
jclassname_case_detail='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
teradata_url='jdbc:teradata://server_url/DBS_PORT=1025,TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8'
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',teradata_url,{'user': user, 'password': password},jars)
curs = conn.cursor()
```

Method 1:
Pandastable to be written => df_out

```
for row in df_out.head().iterrows():
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO TD_table(column1, column2) VALUES(?,?)", row)
```

Error 1

```
Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error
                                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-390-8067f51cb5e3> in <module>
      1 for row in df_out.head().iterrows():
----> 2     curs.execute("INSERT INTO CTD_table(column1, column2) VALUES(?,?)", row)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py in execute(self, operation, parameters)
    492     def execute(self, operation, parameters=None):
    493         if self._connection._closed:
--> 494             raise Error()
    495         if not parameters:
    496             parameters = ()
Error:
```

Method 2:

```
resultset=[]
for column1,column2 in df_out:
    try:
        resultset.append((column1,column2))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
curs.executemany("INSERT INTO CTD_table(column1, column2) VALUES (?,?)",resultset)
```

Error 2

````
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-392-71473191f932> in <module>
      1 resultset=[]
----> 2 for column1,column2 in df_out:
      3     try:
      4         resultset.append((column1,column2))
      5     except AttributeError:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```
````